# ConfigureAwait(false) needed with threadpool threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Assuming I don't care about the synchronization context, is `.ConfigureAwait(false)` needed on await calls when I'm already in a `ThreadPool` thread? For example I started my async operation via:

`await Task.Run(() => myService.DoSomething());`

I know it's important to have if you don't care about the context and you're inside a UI thread or an ASP.NET request, just wondering if it provides the same benefit to async operations outside of those situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a current synchronization context (even if the thread running the code is a thread pool thread) it'll be used.  If you don't want that synchronization context to be used, you'll need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  If there is no current synchronization context then `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't doing anything, as there is no sync context to capture, and whether you have it or not is irrelevant.  If you want the sync context to be captured (regardless of whether the current thread is a thread pool thread or not) then you'll want to not call `ConfigureAwait`.

In short, whether or not you're running as a thread pool thread is irrelevant to the decision as to whether you should capture the synchronization context.